# In perl & Win7, How do I read the character from a specified screen location?

Tags: perl, console

Is it possible, under perl program control, to read a character from the screen?

I'm using Win32::Console::ANSI and Term::ANSIScreen.

My perl program can place the cursor on the desired character with 'locate', but I see no way to read it back into the program.

getc doesn't work, since it requires me to type the character myself.

Example use: filling in a sudoku puzzle on screen.

OK, I could do it easily in Javascript, but I want to be able to write results to a local text file, which JS won't let me do.

Or, is there a way to read the entire screen to a string in memory?

Comment: Don't read from the screen. Keep the state of the puzzle in memory.

Comment: But I need to update the memory by entering a number into a particular box on the screen. it would be a kludge to have to enter the box number and its content from the console, instead of just entering the new content into the box.

Comment: *"I could do it easily in Javascript"* I don't understand you. How would that work?

Comment: How do you propose the user navigates between the boxes on a standard terminal?

Comment: The terminal currently allows SOME forms of mouse I/O, eg, copy and paste to the command line, and also allows output to any address on the screen. I was hoping that someone had put this together to allow me to click on any place on the screen, get a cursor and enter data there, and read it back into perl, e.g. with a getc().

Answer (score 0):

In module  Win32-Console, you have the routine

```
ReadChar [number, col, row]
```